# Adding a post-script to a *.lnk file using cmd code not working as expected

Tags: cmd

I need to insert a post-script into every `*.lnk` file inside a folder.
I have found some codes here and modified them as to reach my goal, but for some reason, every code I use is adding the post-script more than once:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /b "C:\Test\*"') do  ( cd "%i" &  ren *.lnk ??????????????????????????????????????????????????????-18.* )
```

The result of the line above will be that every `*.lnk` file in that folder will be renamed to:

```
example-18-18-18-18-18-18-18-18-18-18-18-18.lnk
```

The desired result is:   `example-18.lnk`

The original filename is:   `example.lnk`

any clue on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `%i`? `for /f %f in ('dir /b "C:\Test\*"')` executes the part after `do` once for every file and every folder in `C:\Test\`. Why do you use a `for /f %f` loop, when you don't use `%f`?

Comment: Well, I can tell you that you have got 12 items in the directory `C:\Test`, right? Anyway, besides the `%f`/`%i` confusion, there are some more issues: I'd replace the sequence of `?` to a single `*`; then I would put `cd /D "C:\Test" &&` before the `for` loop; then I would change the `dir` part to `dir /B /A:-D "*.lnk"` and do `ren "%f" "*-18.lnk"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I am pretty sure that you have got 12 items in the directory `C:\Test`, right? Because it seems the same file `example.lnk` becomes renamed 12 times in a row…

Anyway, there are several problems in your code:

- you have got a `for /f %f` loop but you are using `%i` instead of in the loop body;
- the `for /f` loop together with `dir` are resolving [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) (`*`, `?`), but you are specifying such also in the loop body, that is why the same file becomes renamed again and again;
- move the `cd` command in front of the loop to change the working directory once in advance;
- <s>the sequence of `?`-characters is completely useless, just place a single `*`-character;</s> **edit:** now I got why you are using the sequence of `?`-characters (which do not match the `.`) rather than a single `*`-character (which matches all characters), because `*-18.*` would lead to the string `-18` to be appended *behind* the extension `.lnk`; however, to prevent this you could use [`~`-modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), like `%~nf-18%~xf` or `%~nf-18.*`;

So what about this:

```cmd
cd /D "C:\Test" && for /F "delims= eol=|" %f in ('dir /B /A:-D "*.lnk"') do ren "%f" "%~nf-18.*"
```

This does:

- change ([`cd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html)) to the working directory `C:\Test`, even from a different drive (`/D`);
- execute the following command only in case of success ([`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html));
- let [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) return all files (`/A:-D`) with extension `.lnk` as a bare list (`/B`);
- [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) parses the list line by line not splitting file names (`delims=`) or ignoring any (`eol=|`);
- rename ([`ren`](https://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)) each file (referred to by `%f`) so that its original base name (`%~nf`) gets `-18` appended and the original extension is kept (trailing `.*`);

Comment: Nice! This is almost it! But I am getting the shortcuts renamed to "Test1.lnk-18" instead of "Test1-18.lnk"... I am trying to fiddle with the code you gave to make it work, thanks for the explanations so far!!

Comment: Alright! Thanks @aschipfl ! I got it to work, not the best way to do it I imagine, but gets the job done (although I had to use the sequence of ? instead of * as you suggested): 
cd /D "C:\Test" && for /F "delims= eol=|" %f in ('dir /B /A:-D "*.lnk"') do ren "%f" ??????????????????????????????????????-18.*

Comment: See my edited answer; I was too focussed on all the other mistakes that I did not realise the purpose of the `?`-sequence...

Comment: works like a charm now! thanks for the explanations, now I have a better idea of what the code is actually doing :D